# vCenter 4.0 vim_vcdb database datafile size. How big should it be?

Tags: sql-server-2005, vmware-vcenter

How large should my vim_vcdb database datafile to be?  How much daily change should I expect to see? Should I be looking into some type of data archiving/purging?

I have 9 hosts and 198 VMs. Vcenter is a VM, DB is a physical -SQL2005.

Currently my datafile is 3.1 Gbs. A week ago it was 2.4Gb, this seems like a lot of growth to me. Is this normal to see that much change in a week? Or is there a problem?

The work done in the past week was 15 vstorage moves, 10 P2Vs, a few clones.

Comment: How 'old' is the VC? have you tracked its growth over longer than two weeks?

Comment: about 1.5 years. We recently moved from SQL express to the full  version, which is when we noticed the size. I'm just trying to figure out if thats a normal size.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your statistics settings in Administration - vCenter server settings. THere is a sizing guide there based on your level of logging